# Simple ForEach Combined with If Statment brings wrong results

Tags: windows, loops, powershell, foreach

Im fairly new to PS, im trying to perform a simple task, get list of computers by using the get-content, than though a foreach loop perform a wmi query to each device in the list and  get the OS type, than with a IF statment check perform a different task depends on the OS, everntually win vista 7 8 10 needed to be seperated from xp.
I wrote the following PS script :

```
$computers=Get-Content C:\ComputerList\Computers.txt 
$OSType=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingsystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $computers  


ForEach ( $compdevice in $computers ) {

if ( $OSType.buildnumber -eq "2600*" ) {

Write-Host $compdevice"'s OS type is XP" }

Else  {

Write-Host $compdevice"'s Os type is Newer than xp"

 }
   }
```

in this case i get the same result for all computers ( im running the secret againt 2 win xp 1 win 7 and 1 win 8 in a domain envierment.

I've tried a different variation  also :

```
$computers=Get-Content C:\ComputerList\Computers.txt 
$OSType=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingsystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $computers  


ForEach ( $compdevice in $computers ) {

if ( $OSType.buildnumber -eq "2600*" ) {

Write-Host $compdevice"'s OS type is XP" }

Else  {

Write-Host $compdevice"'s Os type is Newer than xp"

 }
   }
```

in both cases i get the exact same results ( all goes to one option of the IF statement )

I wonder, what am I doing wrong ?
Note - I was trying to filter by caption, buildnumber and version. and even wild card in the IF statement, it doesn't work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong.
First, you have captured wmi content into an array but you do not have a relation of that data to computername. If you include wmi lookup inside the foreach loop, then you have the relationship established. In other words:

```
$computers=Get-Content C:\ComputerList\Computers.txt 

ForEach ( $compdevice in $computers ) {

$OSType=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingsystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $compdevice

### you are using '-eq' so you should provide the actual number, you would use * with -like operator
if ( $OSType.buildnumber -eq "2600" ) {
...
```